# Hadoop error .ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My program is as follows:

```
    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // your map code goes here
            String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");

            for(String str : fields) {
                context.write(new Text(str), new LongWritable(1L));
            }
        }
    }
   public int run(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(TopOS.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJobName("TopOS");
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int ret = ToolRunner.run(new TopOS(), args);
        System.exit(ret);
    }
}
```

My data looks like:

```
123456,Windows,6.1,6394829384232,343534353,23432,23434343,12322
123456,OSX,10,6394829384232,23354353,23432,23434343,63635
123456,Windows,6.0,5396459384232,343534353,23432,23434343,23635
123456,Windows,6.0,6393459384232,343534353,23432,23434343,33635
```

Why am I getting the following error? How can I get around this?

```
Hadoop : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
```

Comment: I dont see where it is that is violating the inheritance tree. The output key is a Text and LongWritable is the output value. Could you expound? I am not seeing what you mean.

Comment: `Mapper<Text, Text, Text, LongWritable>` should change to `Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>`. The key is the file offset of the current line. It's type is LongWritable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from my point of view there is just a small error in your code.

As you are using a flat Textfile as Input the fixed key class is LongWritable (what you don't need/use) and the value class ist Text.

Setting the keyClass in your Mapper to Object to underline that you don't use this, you get rid of your error.

Here is my slightly modified code.

```
package org.woopi.stackoverflow.q22853574;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

public class MapReduceJob {

  public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // your map code goes here
        String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");

        for(String str : fields) {
            context.write(new Text(str), new LongWritable(1L));
        }
    }
  }

    public int run(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(MapReduceJob.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJobName("MapReduceJob");
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    MapReduceJob j = new MapReduceJob();
    int ret = j.run(args);
    System.exit(ret);
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Can you use

```
//Set the key class for the job output data.
job.setOutputKeyClass(Class<?> theClass)
//Set the value class for job outputs
job.setOutputValueClass(Class<?> theClass)
```

instead of setMapOutputKeyClass and setMapOutputValueClass methods.